# No change in output though changes in controller and/or view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, browser

I have just started out with ASP.Net MVC and have encountered a problem I can't solve.

So far I have created a model, a controller and a view and have succeeded with getting things out in the browser, with pure text and ViewBag. However, when I change anything in for example the view (text från "Hello" to "Hello!" or whatever) and starts the project, the new changes isn't there.

I have tried Build, Rebuild, Start debugging, Start without debugging with no luck. I can even delete all the code in the controller and the view and nothing will be changed.

However, if I restart VS and open up the project again, the new changes are applied.

What am I doing wrong?

Note: I know about browser cache and that's not the problem in this case.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't viewing a different site altogether (e.g. if you've published it to an IIS somewhere). Deleting a view should take immediate, very fatal effect to any action that needs it.

Comment: I'm running it locally, so that shouldn't be the case. :/

Comment: I'm not using a database yet, but if you're talking about something internal to VS, I have no idea.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Tried both Chrome and IE. Doesn't seem to have anything to do with the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "clean" option in the build menu. this should delete everything in your projects bin > Debug folder (or Bin > Release if you have that selected). Also you  Also stop  your IIS developer server some times VS doesn't close it properly. It should start when you click build and run. If your project has nothing in it's "bin > Debug" folder or it's "Bin > Release" folder when you rebuild it's not a VS issue and I would look into browser caching at that point.

clean is you friend...